# Input Mismatch Exception Error with Inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract, comparable, mismatch

so I'm writing a program where I have to have a list of items that are either games or movies. Each item has a 3-digit ID number (saved as a string), a title, a price, a stock check(in/out) and a renter name (either a name or empty). I had to have a list of menu items of things to do with these items. The item class is abstract, and both movie and game extend it. Here is the movie store code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class MovieStore
{
  private Item[] items=null;
  private int numItems;

  public MovieStore() //default constructor 
  {
    items=new Item[30];
    numItems=0;
  }

  public MovieStore(String testFileName) throws IOException
  {
    File f=new File(testFileName);
    if(!f.exists())
    {
      System.out.println("File "+testFileName+" does not exist.");
      System.exit(0);
    }
    Scanner input=new Scanner(f);

    items=new Item[30];
    numItems=0;
    String code;
    while (input.hasNext())
    {
      code=input.next();
      if (code.equals("M"))
      {
        String id=input.next();
        String title=input.next();
        double price=input.nextDouble();
        int runTime=input.nextInt();
        String rating=input.next();
        String format=input.next();
        int stockcheck=input.nextInt();
        String renter=input.next();
        if (stockcheck==1) //true, in stock
          items[numItems]=new Movie(id, title, price, true, runTime, rating, format);
        else //false, not in stock
          items[numItems]=new Movie(id, title, price, false, renter, runTime, rating, format);
      }
      else if (code.equals("G"))
      {
        String id=input.next();
        String title=input.next();
        double price=input.nextDouble();
        int stockcheck=input.nextInt();
        int ageLevel=input.nextInt();
        String renter=input.next();
        if (stockcheck==1) //true, in stock
          items[numItems]=new Game(id, title, price, true, ageLevel);
        else //false, not in stock
          items[numItems]=new Game(id, title, price, false, renter, ageLevel);
      }
      numItems++;
    }
    SelectionSort.sort(items, numItems);
  }

  public int search(String id)
  {
    Item key=new Item(id, "", 0.0, true, ""); 
    return (BinarySearch.search(items, numItems, key)); 
  }

  public void addItem(Item s) 
  {
    items[numItems]=s;
    numItems++;
    SelectionSort.sort(items, numItems); 
  }


  public static String menu()
  {
    String code="";
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter one of the following options as a letter.");
    System.out.println("a. Check out an item.");
    System.out.println("b. Check in an item.");
    System.out.println("c. Search an item by ID to see if it is in stock.");
    System.out.println("d. Search an item by name.");
    System.out.println("e. Display inventory.");
    System.out.println("f. Add a new item to the inventory.");
    System.out.println("g. Delete an item from the inventory.");
    System.out.println("h. Display the menu.");
    System.out.println("i. Exit.");
    return (input.next());
  }

  public void performAction(String choice)
  {
    Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
    if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("a"))
    {
      BinarySearch s=new BinarySearch();
      System.out.println("Enter the ID Number of the item.");
      String id=input.next();
      int search=search(id);
      if (search==-1)
        System.out.println("Item not found. Try again.");
      else
      {
        if (items[search].getStock()==false)
          System.out.println("Sorry, this item is out of stock.");
        else
        {
          System.out.println("Please enter the renter's name in the format last,first [with no spaces].");
          String name=input.next();
          items[search].setName(name);
          items[search].setStock(false);
          System.out.println("Item checked out.");
        }
      }
    }
    else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("b"))
    {
      BinarySearch s=new BinarySearch();
      System.out.println("Enter the ID Number of the item.");
      String id=input.next();
      int search=search(id);
      if (search==-1)
        System.out.println("Item not found. Try again.");
      else
      {
        if (items[search].getStock()==true)
          System.out.println("This item is already in stock.");
        else
        {
          items[search].setName("");
          items[search].setStock(true);
          System.out.println("Item checked in.");
        }
      }
    }
    else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("c"))
    {
      BinarySearch s=new BinarySearch();
      System.out.println("Enter the ID Number of the item.");
      String id=input.next();
      int search=search(id);
      if (search==-1)
        System.out.println("Item not found. Try again.");
      else
      {
        if (items[search].getStock()==true)
        {
          System.out.println("This item is in stock.");
          System.out.println(items[search]);
        }
        else
        {
          System.out.println("This item is not in stock.");
          System.out.println(items[search]);
        }
      }
    }
    else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("d"))
    {
      System.out.println("Enter the title of the item [using dashes instead of spaces].");  
      String title=input.next();
      for (int i=0; i<numItems; i++)
      {
        if (title.equals(items[i].title))
        {
          if (items[i].getStock()==true)
          {
            System.out.println("This item is in stock.");
            System.out.println(items[i]);
          }
          else
          {
            System.out.println("This item is not in stock.");
            System.out.println(items[i]);
          }
        }
      }
    }
    else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("e"))
    {
      for (int i=0; i<numItems; i++)
        items[i].display();
    }
    else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("f"))
    {
      System.out.println("Please enter an M for a movie or a G for a game.");
      String type=input.next();
      if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("M"))
      {
        System.out.println("Please enter the ID number for the movie.");
        String id=input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the movie's title (no spaces, dashes instead).");
        String title=input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of the movie.");
        double price=input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the run time of the movie.");
        int runTime=input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Please enter the rating of the movie.");
        String rating=input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the format of the movie, V(HS) or D(VD).");
        String format=input.next();
        Item s=new Movie(id, title, price, true, runTime, rating, format);
        addItem(s);
      }
      else if (type.equalsIgnoreCase("G"))
      {
        System.out.println("Please enter the ID number for the game.");
        String id=input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the games's title (no spaces, dashes instead).");
        String title=input.next();
        System.out.println("Please enter the price of the game.");
        double price=input.nextDouble();
        System.out.println("Please enter the age level of the game.");
        int ageLevel=input.nextInt();
        Item s=new Game(id, title, price, true, ageLevel);
        addItem(s);
      }
      else
        System.out.println("Invalid input. Try again.");
    }
    else if (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("g"))
    {
      System.out.println("Delete item.");
    }
  }


  public static void  main(String [] args) throws IOException
  {
    MovieStore m = new MovieStore("data.txt"); 
    String choice;
    do
    {
      System.out.println();
      choice = m.menu();
      m.performAction(choice);  
      System.out.println();
    } while (!choice.equalsIgnoreCase("I")); //exits when you click i
  }
}
```

The movie and game classes are similar. Item implements comparable and compares based off of ID number. They have different constructors based off of their items, but they are created correctly in the MovieStore program. Here is the file data.txt

```
M 121 The-Departed 4.90 209 R D 0 Underwood,Frank
G 698 Drakes-Uncharted 3.90 0 16 White, Walter
M 345 Frozen 5.50 163 G D 0 Sheeran,Ed
M 768 School-of-Rock 1.99 155 PG V 1 empty
G 904 Lego-Batman 6.77 0 6 Pinkman,Jesse
M 564 The-Hobbit 6.50 255 PG13 D 0 Swift,Taylor
G 532 Wii-Sports 4.35 0 12 Goodman,Saul
M 196 Scarface 3.68 213 R V 1 empty
M 333 Love-Actually 4.58 130 PG13 D 1 empty
M 889 Shutter-Island 6.98 193 PG13 D 0 Smith,Matt
M 508 The-Notebook 3.45 175 PG13 V 1 empty
G 132 Fifa 8.99 0 7 Stark,Ned
G 666 Call-of-Duty 0 16 Snow,Jon
M 401 Titanic 5.90 240 PG13 V 1 empty
M 837 The-Amazing-Spiderman 6.89 198 PG D 0 Pond,Amy
M 424 The-Wolf-of-Wall-Street 9.99 216 R D 0 Lannister,Tyrion
G 999 Battlefield 7.88 1 16 empty
G 444 Borderlands 6.44 1 14 empty
M 774 Mean-Girls 3.50 154 PG13 V 1 empty
M 582 Flight 5.66 201 R D 0 Montgomery,Aria
G 999 Madden 4.33 1 10 empty
M 130 The-Boondock-Saints 6.77 234 R V 0 Beckham,David
M 420 Airplane! 6.55 121 PG V 1 empty
M 699 Inception 7.56 221 PG13 D 0 Mars,Bruno
G 100 Civilization 8.99 1 16 empty
M 834 The-Great-Gatsby 8.55 215 PG13 D 1 empty
M 555 The-Grinch 2.11 121 G V 1 empty
G 333 Pokemon 1.50 1 6 empty
M 800 21-Jump-Street 5.10 200 PG13 D 1 empty
M 945 Pitch-Perfect 7.89 191 PG13 D 0 Cyrus,Miley
```

And here is the error I am getting when I run the program:

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:840)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1461)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2091)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2050)
    at MovieStore.<init>(MovieStore.java:51)
    at MovieStore.main(MovieStore.java:233)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacCompiler.runCommand(JavacCompiler.java:272)
```

If you could just explain the error and let me know what I'm doing wrong, that would be great! Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2):

I would have just added this as a comment but I do not have the reputation to add comments yet.

It looks like the problem is with the input file and not necessarily the code.

If you read that API about what could cause the InputMismatchException when using the scanner object this will make sense.

The second line of your input file had a space in the name of the renter of the movie/game. The scanner.next() call will read off of the buffer up to that space. This is causing the scanner to pick up the name up until the point at the space then the rest of the name is waiting to be read. Once the scanner.nextInt() is called you are expecting to read an int but there is a string sitting on the buffer causing the InputMismatch exception.

```
G 698 Drakes-Uncharted 3.90 0 16 White, Walter
```

Comment: Good spot with the space!